# sort dictionary datasets based on values in ascending order

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, sorting, dictionary

i want to sort my dataset and use an example dataset to chack the code. that works and here is the code:

```
var b=ee.List([4.5,2.8,7.4])
var c= ee.List(['a','b','c'])
print('b',b)
var dict=ee.Dictionary.fromLists(c,b)
print('dict',dict)
var ssf=b.sort()
print('ssf',ssf)
var getindex = function(x) {
  return ssf.indexOf(x);
};
var valsb = b.map(getindex);
print('valsb',valsb)


var getval = function(x) {
  return dict.values().get(x);
};
var xz=ee.List(valsb)
var vals = xz.map(getval);
print('vals',vals)
```

the results are as follow which i need and expect to be:

```
b
[4.5,2.8,7.4]
dict
Object (3 properties)
ssf
[2.8,4.5,7.4]
valsb
[1,0,2]
vals
[2.8,4.5,7.4]
```

now i want to apply this example code to my real dataset. but results are deferent as presented bellow

```
var K=ee.Dictionary({
  Type_1: 1.8464303127715112,
  Type_10: 6.355350676676452,
  Type_11: 2.1953842888445907,
  Type_12: 1.8320499546007996,
  Type_13: 11.422968425774258,
  Type_14: 17.77039967032645,
  Type_15: 1.6889244502807435,
  Type_16: 6.766611008880639,
  Type_17: 17.517118575392672,
  Type_2: 0.15007259905911005,
  Type_3: 1.5064320757727172,
  Type_4: 2.318244235030834,
  Type_5: 7.505280367727764,
  Type_6: 1.1614314188052866,
  Type_7: 8.901825525058984,
  Type_8: 6.9262150730973815,
  Type_9: 4.135261341899796
})
var b=ee.List(K.values())
print('b',b)
var c= ee.List(K.keys())
print('c',c)
var dict=ee.Dictionary.fromLists(c,b)
print('dict',dict)

var ssf=b.sort()
print('ssf',ssf)
var getindex = function(x) {
  return ssf.indexOf(x);
};
var valsb = b.map(getindex);
print('valsb',valsb)


var getval = function(x) {
  return dict.values().get(x);
};
var xz=ee.List(valsb)
var vals = xz.map(getval);
print('vals',vals)
```

the last results presented below:

```
valsb
[5,9,6,4,14,16,3,10,15,0,2,7,12,1,13,11,8]
vals
List (17 elements)
0: 17.77039967032645
1: 0.15007259905911005
2: 1.6889244502807435
3: 11.422968425774258
4: 8.901825525058984
5: 4.135261341899796
6: 1.8320499546007996
7: 1.5064320757727172
8: 6.9262150730973815
9: 1.8464303127715112
10: 2.1953842888445907
11: 6.766611008880639
12: 7.505280367727764
13: 6.355350676676452
14: 1.1614314188052866
15: 2.318244235030834
16: 17.517118575392672
```

in fact the code return the values so that the first element of dict (1.8464303127715112) should be in 5th position in last sorted dataset
and the second value (6.355350676676452) should be in 9th position and so on. but do not sort as in the first simple example

how should i solve that

and here is the ful code for both of the sample and main codes

sample code:
https://code.earthengine.google.com/?scriptPath=users%2FSolmaz%2FBurdur_Sentinel_CloudFree%3ACallDictValues_Test

main code:

https://code.earthengine.google.com/?scriptPath=users%2FSolmaz%2FBurdur_Sentinel_CloudFree%3Aindexcheck

Answer (score 2):

You were advised in a previous question that dictionaries don't preserve order. So, it is not true that the first element of dict (1.8464303127715112) should be in 6th position in last sorted dataset and, the second value (6.355350676676452) should be in 10th position and, so on, because these values are unfailingly joined to its keys.

The above reasoning is only valid in ssf sorted list; not in your dictionary named dict. You cannot first sort values because there is not way to know what happened to keys if you don't use lists.

In following [code](https://code.earthengine.google.com/732c6891cf6f74164976dc5dcfb09206), you can see for printed **values_in_dict** list, obtained for mapping unsorted keys named as **c**, that your original dictionary K is identical to new dictionary dict. If you want a different behavior so, you need to use paired **ee.List** objects; not dictionaries.

```
var K=ee.Dictionary({
  Type_1: 1.8464303127715112,
  Type_10: 6.355350676676452,
  Type_11: 2.1953842888445907,
  Type_12: 1.8320499546007996,
  Type_13: 11.422968425774258,
  Type_14: 17.77039967032645,
  Type_15: 1.6889244502807435,
  Type_16: 6.766611008880639,
  Type_17: 17.517118575392672,
  Type_2: 0.15007259905911005,
  Type_3: 1.5064320757727172,
  Type_4: 2.318244235030834,
  Type_5: 7.505280367727764,
  Type_6: 1.1614314188052866,
  Type_7: 8.901825525058984,
  Type_8: 6.9262150730973815,
  Type_9: 4.135261341899796
});

var b=ee.List(K.values());
print('b',b);

var c= ee.List(K.keys());
print('c',c);

var dict=ee.Dictionary.fromLists(c,b);
print('dict',dict);

var ssf=b.sort();
print('ssf',ssf);

var getindex = function(x) {
  return ssf.indexOf(x);
};

var valsb = b.map(getindex);
print('valsb',valsb);

var values_in_dict = c.map(function (key) {
  
  return dict.get(key);
  
});

print("values_in_dict", values_in_dict);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer for my question as i need:

I messed up parameters in coding.

```
var K=ee.Dictionary({
  Type_1: 1.8464303127715112,
  Type_10: 6.355350676676452,
  Type_11: 2.1953842888445907,
  Type_12: 1.8320499546007996,
  Type_13: 11.422968425774258,
  Type_14: 17.77039967032645,
  Type_15: 1.6889244502807435,
  Type_16: 6.766611008880639,
  Type_17: 17.517118575392672,
  Type_2: 0.15007259905911005,
  Type_3: 1.5064320757727172,
  Type_4: 2.318244235030834,
  Type_5: 7.505280367727764,
  Type_6: 1.1614314188052866,
  Type_7: 8.901825525058984,
  Type_8: 6.9262150730973815,
  Type_9: 4.135261341899796
})
var b=ee.List(K.values())
print('b',b)
var c= ee.List(K.keys())
print('c',c)
var dict=ee.Dictionary.fromLists(c,b)
print('dict',dict)

var ssf=b.sort()
print('ssf',ssf)
var getindex = function(x) {
  return b.indexOf(x);
};
var valsb = ssf.map(getindex);
print('valsb',valsb)


var getval = function(x) {
  return dict.values().get(x);
};
var vals = valsb.map(getval);
print('vals',vals)
```

The code is here:

https://code.earthengine.google.com/?scriptPath=users%2FSolmaz%2FBurdur_Sentinel_CloudFree%3Aindexcheck